# Web application licence suggestions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, licensing

There are 3 different licence type in MS-SQL server 2012:

- Enterprise
- Business Intelligence
- Standard

What is their properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could make out of your question, Standard is what you probably need.  Enterprise adds in additional high availability features, advanced BI options and ups the limits of memory and CPU.  BI edition is mostly beneficial for data warehousing without the added expense of Enterprise.

Here is a good breakdown on functionality:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx